# RawArray not modified by processes as shared memory for Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am working with python multiprocessing. Using Pool to start concurrent processes and RawArray to share an array between concurrent processes. I do not need to synchronize the accessing of RawArray, that is, the array can be modified by any processes at any time.

The test code for RawArray is: (do not mind the meaning of the program as it is just a test.)

```
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import RawArray

import time

sieve = RawArray('i', (10 + 1)*[1])   # shared memory between processes

import multiprocessing as mp

def foo_pool(x):
        time.sleep(0.2)
        sieve[x] = x*x  # modify the shared memory array. seem not work ?    
        return x*x

result_list = []

def log_result(result):  
        result_list.append(result)

def apply_async_with_callback():
        pool = mp.Pool(processes = 4)    
        for i in range(10):
            pool.apply_async(foo_pool, args = (i,), callback = log_result)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        print(result_list)  

        for x in sieve:
            print (x)        # !!! sieve is [1, 1, ..., 1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
        apply_async_with_callback()
```

While the code did not work as expected. I commented the key statements. I have got stuck on this for a whole day. Any help or constructive advices would be very appreciated.

Comment: Just tried running your code on MacOS with Python 3.6 - everything works ok, sieve is printed 1,4,9,16,25 ...

Answer (score 0):

- `time.sleep` fails because you did not `import time`
- use `sieve[x] = x*x` to modify the array instead of `sieve[x].value = x*x`
- on Windows, your code creates a new `sieve` in each subprocess. You need to pass a reference to the shared array, for example like this:

  ```
  def foo_init(s):
      global sieve
      sieve = s

  def apply_async_with_callback():
      pool = mp.Pool(processes = 4, initializer=foo_init, initargs=(sieve,))    

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      sieve = RawArray('i', (10 + 1)*[1])
  ```

Comment: Karlila, Thanks for your time. I just reedited the code. And now the shared memory sieve is still not modified (it is [1, 1, ... ]). What am I missing? More clearly, my problem is how to modify an shared array (RawArray) in concurrent processes without copying it in each processes?

Comment: @user3349785 Added one more thing to the answer. Note, by the way, that you should not change a question in a way that makes existing answers invalid.

Comment: Sorry for changing the question (I misstook some code the first time and just want to make the question more clear. Actually this is the first time I ask a questin on SO. I donot know the rule very much. )  What you mean "your code creates a new sieve in each subprocess"? I didnot pass the shared array sieve to each process but just modify one of its elements by "sieve[x] = x*x " in subprocess foo_pool.

Comment: @user3349785 On Windows, `multiprocessing` imports the main module into a fresh process. That executes the `sieve = ...` line and creates an independent array in the child process. Check the `sharedctypes` examples in the docs, the shared variables are always passed to the subprocesses as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You should use multithreading instead of multiprocessing, as threads can share memory of main process natively.

If you worry about python's GIL mechanism, maybe you can resort to the [`nogil`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html#nogil) of `numba`.

Answer (score 0):

Working version:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, RawArray
import time


def foo_pool(x):
    sieve[x] = x * x  # modify the shared memory array.


def foo_init(s):
    global sieve
    sieve = s


def apply_async_with_callback(loc_size):
    with Pool(processes=4, initializer=foo_init, initargs=(sieve,)) as pool:
        pool.map(foo_pool, range(loc_size))

    for x in sieve:
        print(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    size = 50
    sieve = RawArray('i', size * [1])  # shared memory between processes
    apply_async_with_callback(size)
```

Comment: Although code is useful, it's better to provide supplementary explanations for it when submitting answers.